# Confused regarding the use of Message::ParseFromIstream in Protocol Buffers

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am receiving the data as `unsigned char*`, which contains a byte array.

```
unsigned char* byteptr = static_cast<unsigned char*>(msg.data());
```

I want to initialize my protocol buffer which is an address book. I think the best possible match is to use [ParseFromIstream](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message.ParseFromIstream.details) is following:

```
my_address_book.ParseFromIstream()
```

Regarding the byte array, which is `unsigned char*`. Since the length of the byte array is not known at compile time, there are two options:

Option 1. Variable length array

```
unsigned char bytearray[msg.size()];
std::copy(byteptr, byteptr + msg.size(), bytearray);
```

Option 2. Dynamically allocated array and delete it once done

```
unsigned char* bytearray = new unsigned char [msg.size()];
std::copy(byteptr, byteptr + msg.size(), bytearray);
```

I have following questions:

1. How to use `ParseFromIstream` in case of `unsigned char*`?
2. Considering that the better performance (fast execution speed) is the priority, which option is best among above two?

Comment: `Message` inherits from `MessageLite`, so [you can use the `MessageLite` functions too](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite). Check `ParseFromString`, [`ParseFromCodedStream`, `ParseFromZeroCopyStream`, or `ParseFromBoundedZeroCopyStream`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.coded_stream) and use the one that best matches your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`ParseFromArray()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#MessageLite.ParseFromArray), which takes a pointer and a size:

```
my_address_book.ParseFromArray(msg.data(), msg.size())
```

There is no need to copy the data to a new array at all.

Comment: I will try your suggestion and let you know the results soon. Thank you very much.